# importing mysql database to RDS

Tags: mysql, rds

I am trying to dump my local mysql database data to an RDS database. I use the following command in windows command:

```
mysqldump -u <username> <localdbname> --single-transaction --compress --order-by-primary 
-p<localdbpassword> > mysql -u <rdsusername> --port=3306 --host=<host> -p<rdspassword>
```

I noticed that I get a database doesn't exist when the name of my local database and rds database differ. But when they have the same name, this command runs but nothing happens. How should I change it?

Comment: do you have a big file named 'mysql' in that directory now? (you should use the pipe sign)